# need outputs for programs i have in masm enviroment but cant install it in my laptop it is providing error

Tags: masm

include Irvine32.inc
.data
prompt db "Enter your choice (1 for rock, 2 for paper, 3 for scissors): ", 0
resultMsg db "You ", 0 winMsg db "win!", 0 loseMsg db "lose.", 0 tieMsg db "It's a tie.", 0
.code
main PROC
mov eax, 0 ; seed for random number generation
call Randomize
mov edx, OFFSET prompt
call WriteString
call ReadInt ; Read user's choice
mov ecx, eax ; Store user's choice in ecx
mov eax, 3
call RandomRange
add eax, 1 ; Adjust the range to 1-3
mov ebx, eax ; Store computer's choice in ebx
cmp ecx, ebx
je tie
ja win
jmp lose
win: mov edx, OFFSET winMsg
jmp showResult
lose:
mov edx, OFFSET loseMsg
jmp showResult
tie: mov edx, OFFSET tieMsg
showResult: mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1 ; file descriptor 1 is stdout
mov ecx, edx ; pointer to the message
mov edx, 10 ; length of the message
int 0x80 ; call kernel
call Crlf ; Move to the next line
invoke ExitProcess, 0
main ENDP
END main

need output for this